# How to update mongoose version which has come as part of "express-mvc-platform" npm module in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I've been using `express-mvc-platform` npm module to design my application's folder structure. It's working fine.

But now it's giving errors when am using some other modules like `mongoose-paginate-v2` which are dependent on newest versions of mongoose and mongodb.

`express-mvc-platform` npm module still has older versions of mongoose and mongodb as it wasn't updated in last 2 years. But I've to update the mongoose to the newest version as per my requirements. But I couldn't able to do that. I've got mongoose and mongodb modules as part of this module. How to update both mongo db and mongoose node modules?

Is there any other npm modules for express framework to automatically create mvc type project folder structure with required folders?

Comment: I can’t even find the repo for the package you mention. This is a good reminder to try and use packages that are well maintained. You could always fork the repo and update the dependencies, but that may also require significant refactoring of the module.

Comment: Is it this? https://github.com/solid-stack/mvc-express-mongoose.  That module is simple and you can likely just copy or reimplement that one file in your own project.

Comment: ```express-mv-platform``` is the module I'm talking about, @Joe

Comment: can you post a link to npmjs for that package?  I can't find it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mvc-platform